# Merging/aggregating disqus

Tags: merge, comments, aggregate, disqus

Odd question - Would it be possible to merge two disqus widgets so they aggregate comments from between two sources?

So say if you have two identical articles, A and B, on two separate websites that both have disqus. Is there anyway so that when person X comments on article A and person Y comments on article B, that the disqus thread of both A and B will include the comments from X and Y?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, this is basic usage of a 'disqus_identifier' which is documented here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472099

The one caveat here is that a unique thread on Disqus can only have one link-to URL (which is what we use for Discovery, notification alerts, etc.), so you have to pick the preferred website for that.

If we assume that you have two websites at http://mycoolwebsite.com/ and http://example.com/, and "mycoolwebsite.com" is the preferred link-to site, you would use the same exact embed code on both sites. Here's an example:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: THIS CODE IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'example'; // Make sure you use the same shortname on both sites
    var disqus_identifier = 'some_unique_identifier_for_your_discussion';
    var disqus_title = 'The Title of the article';
    var disqus_url = 'http://mycoolwebsite.com/2013/a-cool-article/'; // Make sure this is the same, even on example.com

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

The other caveat is to make sure that if you've set trusted (whitelisted) domains in your Disqus site settings, to make sure both domains are included.